# Best way to define true, false, unset state

Tags: java, boolean

If you have a situation where you need to know where a boolean value wasn't set (for example if that unset value should inherit from a parent value) the Java boolean primitive (and the equivalent in other languages) is clearly not adequate.

What's the best practice to achieve this?  Define a new simple class that is capable of expressing all three states or use the Java Boolean class and use null to indicate the unset state?

Comment: Like http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx of course :)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
Boolean a = true;
Boolean b = false;
Boolean c = null;
```

I would use that. It's the most straight-forward.

Another way is to use an enumeration. Maybe that's even better and faster, since no boxing is required:

```
public enum ThreeState {
    TRUE,
    FALSE,
    TRALSE
};
```

There is the advantage of the first that users of your class doesn't need to care about your three-state boolean. They can still pass `true` and `false`. If you don't like the `null`, since it's telling rather little about its meaning here, you can still make a `public static final Boolean tralse = null;` in your class.

Comment: The Daily WTF website says that the 3rd value should be named "FILE_NOT_FOUND".  See: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx

Comment: I'd go with the Boolean, myself.  The whole TRUE, FALSE, FILE_NOT_FOUND/TRALSE thing is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Bad design.  Make a tri-state object.  Instantiate it with the parent to automate value inheritance when "unset", otherwise that test/use parent is going to be spread throughout your code.

Comment: Bill, i'm not a java programmer. feel free to post your solution in your answer. i will upvote it if it's nice :)

Comment: Is this a good design or bad one -- depends on the context. No reason to over complicate things if all you need is an "N/A" flag in one piece of the code.

Comment: I didn't do this but instead made wrapper class called Property that held the unset state.  This is because I had other types with the same requirement, (Integer and Color).  For each one the unset state could have been represented with null though.

Comment: An additional benefit of the enum is you can implement your own `or` and not have to worry about nulls. `if (this == TRUE) return this; else return other;`

Comment: it's a good solution for general java usage. but regarding this solution in java/android, it is not a good idea when implementing multiples enums.

Answer (score 19):

In Java 8, there is also the **Optional** option:

```
public static final Optional<Boolean> TRI_TRUE = Optional.of(true);
public static final Optional<Boolean> TRI_FALSE = Optional.of(false);
public static final Optional<Boolean> TRI_UNKNOWN = Optional.empty();
```

As a bonus, you will get all those *map* and *consume* methods.

Comment: If one cannot use Java 8 but Guava is present, `com.google.common.base.Optional` can be used instead.

Comment: Seems like using `Optional` for fields is anti-pattern now [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/1wPsKTA.png)

Comment: There's also a compiler warning if Optional is used for parameters

Answer (score 10):

Although not Java-specific, my own preference in this scenario is to define a ThreeState class or enumeration and use it -- just as you mentioned, a True, a False and an Undefined (or Default, or Unset, as your domain-specific terminology dictates). It feels better, more natural and more self-documenting than representing unset/undefined with `null`.

Comment: This is absolutely the way to go.  Also, you can refer to the "Parent" in your class so that you can automatically inherit it's state. Otherwise you have the "inherit state" code spread throughout your code (not DRY).

Comment: Bill, what the heck do you mean by "Parent" ?

Answer (score 10):

The @Nullable `Boolean` gets my vote.

Answer (score 6):

Using nulls to represent the state of something is poor design. It's undescriptive and hard to maintain. I would rather have a State object with a default state if nothing has been explicitly set on it. For example:

```
if(state == null) {
    doSomething();
}
```

This doesn't tell me anything about what the expected state is. Something more like this makes it more clear.

```
if(state.awaitingSet()) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Not to mention extensible. What happens when you need a *fourth* state?

Answer (score 2):

I would simply use a int (integer) with values 0,1,2 and handle within program.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Here you mention it would be unset if it has to inherit its value from a parent value. Do you have some kind of data hierarchy? Something like this:

```
Parent a { 
    boolean val = true;
    boolean val2 = false; 
}
Child b {
    boolean val = false;
    //here val2 should be unset!
}
```

In this case, if it's possible, I'd say simply don't include val2 in the Child, and have your lookup logic be such that if it doesn't find the variable, it searches the parents for the value.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @voho, Optional also plays nicely with lambda, making a potentially cleaner structure:

```
public class Node {
  private Node parent;
  private Optional<Boolean> something = Optional.empty();

  public boolean isSomething() {
    return something.orElseGet(() -> {
      if (parent != null)
        return parent.isSomething();
      return false;
    });
  }

  public void setSomething(boolean v) {
    this.something = Optional.of(v);
  }
}
```

However, it's still not obviously that much better than Boolean and a null check:

```
public class Node {
  private Node parent;
  private Boolean something;

  public boolean isSomething() {
    if (something != null)
      return something;
    if (parent != null)
      return parent.isSomething();
    return false;
  }

  public void setSomething(boolean v) {
    this.something = v;
  }
}
```

Comment: Using `Optional` for fields might be problematic [link to comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314800/best-way-to-define-true-false-unset-state#comment122668870_34508429)

Comment: @xardbaiz Good point if the class is Serializable.

Answer (score -1):

In the Parent class initiate the boolean to null and in the child class build a method to check to see if the boolean has been set

in Parent class

```
private Boolean a = null;

public void setA(Boolean a) {
    this.a = a;
}


public Boolean getA() {
    return a;
}
```

In the Child Class

```
if (a == true)
{
dothis;
}
else if (a == false)
{
dothat;
}
else
{
assert false : "Boolean a has not been set";
}
```

Make sure that assertions are turned on. Assertions are only for the development cycle and test cycle, they are not for runtime exceptions.

Answer (score -3):

java.lang.Boolean does this for you. There are static constants Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.False.

private Boolean myBoolean;

should be all you need.Note that Boolean.TRUE will pass an equivalence test but is distinct from "true" (which gets autoboxed to TRUE).