# I need a three-valued logic in Java

Tags: java, threestate

I have tried to return `null` as third value in my boolean function, but it won't compile. I need to return three values from my class method - `true`,  `false` and `null` (for example). Is there any standard way how can I do it?

Comment: Use `Boolean`, not `boolean`.

Comment: It's hard to say without more information, but if neither `true` nor `false` apply after your computation, it might make sense to `throw an Exception` rather than return null.

Comment: OK, you originally wrote this method to return a `boolean` because you thought that two values would be enough.  Now you need a third.  Why are you now sure that three will always be enough?  Probably best to define an `enum` so you can extend it later if you need to, or rethink your logic.

Comment: I have tried Boolean, but I couldn't pass received null as input parameter for other function. Only enum or counter, eh?

Comment: There is nothing 'unclear' about 'three-valued logic'. Come off it guys. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use an enumeration with three values defined. Hacking things together is no solution.

Comment: I know about enumerators but I suppose there are some ternary-logic( why misusing me?

Comment: The problem with returning null is, that no-one knows what it means. You should write documentation, stating that null is a valid return value, or expect applications to throw exceptions when using your function.

Comment: I think you mean "enumeration". Enumerators are used for looping over a collection.

Comment: Or, to use the language keyword, define an `enum`.

Answer (score -1):

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314800/best-way-to-define-true-false-unset-state) has been asked, it should help.

You can make your own POJO object with this logic in getXX() method. From your method return this POJO with value and test it in code.

Generaly, don't use null values as state indicators.